# Pelican plantuml plugin not rendering diagrams

Tags: python, plugins, pelican, plantuml

I want to generate diagrams from .md files. For some reason the plantuml markup is not recognized and as a result there are no diagrams generated.

I have a working Pelican setup. (see debug log)
Also the plantuml jar is installed and working.

N.B. The warning about MD_EXTENSIONS can't be addressed because the plugin has not yet been adapted for this.

Any debugging hints or suggestions ?

Test post

```
Title: Test UML plugin1
Date: 2016-08-26

PRIMA

::uml:: classes="uml pippo" alt='Immagine del" diagramma uml'

    actor Pipe
    participant Topolino
    Pippo -> Topolino: chiama

    Pippo <-- Topolino: risponde
  ::end-uml::


DOPO

::uml:: format="png" alt="Sample sequence diagram" participant User

User -> A: DoWork activate A #FFBBBB

A -> A: Internal call activate A #DarkSalmon

A -> B: << createRequest >> activate B

B -> A: RequestCreated deactivate B deactivate A A -> User: Done deactivate A
::end-uml::

Test

::uml::

   [First component]
   [Another component] as Comp2
   component Comp3
   component [Last\ncomponent] as Comp4

::end-uml::
```

Debug info

```
DEBUG: Pelican version: 3.7.0
DEBUG: Python version: 2.7.10
WARNING: MD_EXTENSIONS is deprecated use MARKDOWN instead. Falling back to the default.
DEBUG: Adding current directory to system path
DEBUG: Temporarily adding PLUGIN_PATHS to system path
DEBUG: Loading plugin `plantuml`
DEBUG: Registering plugin `plantuml`
DEBUG: Restoring system path

DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.extra".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.smart_strong".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.smart_strong.SmartEmphasisExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.fenced_code".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.fenced_code.FencedCodeExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.footnotes".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.footnotes.FootnoteExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.attr_list".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.attr_list.AttrListExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.def_list".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.def_list.DefListExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.tables".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.tables.TableExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.abbr".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.abbr.AbbrExtension".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.extra.ExtraExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.codehilite".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.codehilite.CodeHiliteExtension".
DEBUG: Successfuly imported extension module "markdown.extensions.meta".
DEBUG: Successfully loaded extension "markdown.extensions.meta.MetaExtension".
```

Comment: Did a test with a file in rst format. This is rendering OK, so the setup of the plantuml  is not the issue. I guess the problem is with the uml directive that is not recognized, probably because of a syntax error.